# Layout differencies in Interface Builder and real device screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I' m developing an application for both Retina 3.5 and Retina 4 screens (iPhone family). And I encountered with the next problem. I create a view in `.xib` file and set size to Retina 3.5 full screen.At the very bottom of the screen I placed a `view` with `UILabel`. You can see the view on the screen:
[image]

As you can see the view is at the very bottom. But when I run the application either on device or the simulator view with label on some reason doesn't fit the screen:
[image]

So the question - what can be the problem? How can I fix this? Why IB view sizes is not correct?

Comment: the status bar is shown but not in Interface Builder.

Comment: What auto-resizing / auto-layout are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your NIB to not have a status bar, but your app *does* have one. This means your NIB is sized at 480 pts high (on a 3.5" screen), when it should in fact be 460 (due to the status bar). This pushes your view down by the corresponding height (20 pts, which you can see at your cut-off label at the bottom).

There are a number of fixes for this. You could just tell your NIB it has a status bar, but a better option would be to set your view to resize dynamically according to its bounds. Exactly how you do this will depend on whether you're using auto-layout or not, but you'll want to check 'autoresize subviews' and make sure your view elements stay locked where you want them to.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I really forgot about it. But can you please explain how can I do this: "but a better option would be to set your view to resize dynamically according to its bounds".
P.S. I don't use autolayout.

Comment: If you don't use auto-layout then that means just a) setting your main view to autoresize subviews, and b) applying an appropriate autoresizing mask to the view (probably `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`. You can set masks in IB, under the 'dimensions' tab of the inspector).